# Pass context to a non-Activity Class to use AssetManager.getAssets()

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I am working on an android app and I am trying to open an xml file in assets folder containing references to images located also in assets folder. I am using AssetManager in a non-activity Class and tried to pass context to its constructor with no success.There are no errors in Eclipse but when I run the app it crushes. The code I use for the 2 classes and the XML is below.

XML File:

```
<scene>

   <sprite>
     <img src="100789.jpg" positionx="100" positiony="200" name="100789.jpg"/>
   </sprite>

   <sprite>
     <img src="100788.jpg" positionx="2" positiony="20" name="100788" />
   </sprite>

</scene>
```

Main Class (Activity)

```
import android.content.Context;
....

public class Test extends AndroidGame {

     Context context=getApplicationContext();

     @Override
     public Screen getStartScreen() {
         return new LoadingScreen(this, context); 
   }
}
```

Load Class (Screen)

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
....

public class LoadingScreen extends Screen {
    private Context context;
    public Document doc;

  public LoadingScreen(Game game, Context context) {
    super(game);
    this.context=context;
}

AssetManager gi = con.getAssets();

@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {


try {

    InputStream inStream = gi.open("assets.xml");
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(inStream);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


}catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }


    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    Assets.background = g.newPixmap(doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("sprite").item(0).getChildNodes().item(1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue(), PixmapFormat.RGB565);
    ....
    ....
    game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));




}
```

So am I doing something wrong ?

I have also tried to put the following code in the constructor with no success:

```
public LoadingScreen(Game game, Context context) {
    super(game);
    this.context=context;

AssetManager gi = con.getAssets();
try {
    InputStream inStream = gi.open("assets.xml");
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(inStream);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


}catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `context` (the `Context` member) before you initialise it, causing a `NullPointerException`.
move `AssetManager gi = con.getAssets();` inside the method

```
@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {
  AssetManager gi = context.getAssets();
   ...

}
```

Comment: He has `this.context` con is not delcared. I think its a typo error op has

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing it out. Still, he says that the application crashes: *here are no errors in Eclipse but when I run the app it crushes.* @Raghunandan

Answer (score 0):

Since `AndroidGame` class inherits from an `Activity` you have to keep in mind the activity life cycle. An activity doesn't have a `Context` until just before `onCreate()` is called and calling  `getApplicationContext()` before then will return null. So you need to set the context field inside of onCreate.

Basically

```
public class Test extends AndroidGame {

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    ...

}
```